# Theme Icons not visible on http://domain.com, works on http://ipaddress

Tags: shortcode, htaccess

I have a wordpress based website released. I have used a theme, that allows icons to be used. These icons are not small images, but shortcodes that I use on the page.

Open

```
http://<my ip address>
```

You will notice nice icons for bullets and slider arrows. But if you open the same website using the domain name

```
http://<my domain name>
```

You will notice that the icons are not visible. Instead just rectangular boxes. What am I missing here ?

**Edit :**

I have modified my .htaccess and restarted apache, and still get this error on my web debugger (Chrome F12)

> > Font from origin 'http://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://>' is therefore not allowed access.

My .htaccess

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
```

**What Finally Worked**

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**One more missing piece of the puzzle**

`.htaccess` file was not being read only. I figured out that I did not have a `httpd.conf` in `/etc/apache2` folder. Realized that apache2 has changed the location of its conf file to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

I added 4 lines just under

> DocumentRoot /var/www/html

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Note my `.htaccess` is under `/var/www/html`

And my .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# Web fonts
AddType application/font-woff woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot

# Browsers usually ignore the font MIME types and sniff the content,
# however, Chrome shows a warning if other MIME types are used for the
# following fonts.
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttc ttf
AddType font/opentype otf

# Make SVGZ fonts work on iPad:
# https://twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType     image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

</IfModule>

# rewrite www.example.com → example.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Dont forget to replace example.com in the above .htaccess. And yes one more thing, `chwon www-data:www-data .htaccess` is important too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see that on mcruiseon.com your console drops this error? I guess this is related to your icon issue

> Font from origin 'http://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577981/font-from-origin-has-been-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: I am trying to figure out where in the .htaccess to add this line `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" `

Comment: you should see it on any webdeveloper tool. In Google Chrome -> F12

Comment: can you please improve your answer.. I would like to keep SO clean. As of now the answer is in my question. Feel free to add it to  your answer. I'll clean up the question after that.